# How to format TimeWithZone to display time like DD/MM/YYYY on Ruby

Tags: ruby, timezone

If I print my TimeWithZone object, it will show:

```
@issue.created_on.to_s

"=> 2013-10-28 18:12:23 UTC "
```

I would like to know a way to print the TimeZone as indicated below:

```
"=> 28/10/2013 18:12:23"
```

How Can I do It?

Comment: try this method http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strftime`:

```
Time.new(2013, 10, 28, 18, 12, 23).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
=> "28/10/2013 18:12:23"
```